# Unwanted patches of colour in Matlab EPS and PDF figures

Tags: image, matlab, pdf, eps

I have a figure produced using the `image` function in Matlab 2014b. The image looks perfect in the figure window, but when I save it to a PDF or EPS file, it produces patches of colour that don't appear in the figure window. When using `export_fig`, this happens in both the PDF and EPS file formats, and when using `print`, it only shows up in the EPS file, not the PDF. However, some other weird stuff happens using the `print` function, so I would prefer not to use that.

The figure is a 3 x 4 set of maps, and the extra patches of colour can be seen in the snapshot below (at the bottom of each map and to the right of the MJJ map). I have been deleting them by hand in Illustrator, but I have a large amount of these figures so I need to stop it happening at the Matlab end really.

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on with this and how to fix it?

FYI, this is the code I am using to make the figures (amongst other lines to get it to look exactly like this):

```
h=image(lon_data,lat_data,plot_data);
```

And this to export the figures:

```
export_fig(filename,'-painters','-eps','-pdf','-r600')
```

**Edited to add:** this is how it should look - no extra bits at the bottom or sides of the maps. Sometimes the bit to the right happens further down too.

[image]

Comment: The images you posted: are they the good or the bad ones? It is unclear. Can you post something like: expected result and what you have?

Comment: Apologies. Those are the bad ones. I will add one that doesn't have the extra patches on it.

Comment: Hopefully that is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks, it is. I reccomend you that you dubmitt your problem to: https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues , so the developers of export_fig know about this.

Comment: Additionally try: Using only 1 output format. Different resolutions. the `-nocrop` option.

Comment: Using only 1 output format doesn't change anything. I had been exporting solely to EPS until today and I still had the issue. I have to have 600dpi resolution. Not tried the `-nocrop` option though. I don't think the problem is solely caused by `export_fig` because it does it using the `print` function too.

Comment: Yes, but export_fig shoudl work properly when the others (as print) doesnt

Comment: Having looked at some other bugs on the github link, it seems to be caused by the `painters` renderer. I changed it to the `opengl` one, and the problem has gone away. It just means I can't do editing on the figures afterwards, but I don't need to now. I will still report it to them though,

Comment: Its nice that you spot it! Recently export_fig has changed owners hands and I think they are making huge progress into making it better. Please, answe your own question and reffer that this has been flagged as a bug in the github repo. It will be useful for the community

Answer (score 1):

Having done some research, this seems to be caused by the `painters` renderer. The problem goes away when using the `opengl` renderer instead, but this does have other repercussions (I can't edit the image elsewhere using this renderer).

It has been reported as a bug with the developer of `export_fig` here: https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/61